# WPF multiline TextBox does not render as multiline

Tags: c#, wpf

Having the following XAML with Grid in the Window (it could be the only element in the Window):

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" AcceptsTab="True" MinLines="5" MaxLines="5">
        Any text
    </TextBox>
</Grid>
```

When I run the application then the TextBox is not multilined:
[image: TextBox with no multiline]

However when I make any edit in the TextBox then it immediately rerenders correctly:
[image: TextBox after editting]

What is causing this issue and how to fix it (I would prefer not to hack anything if it is posssible)?

Comment: my guess would be the "Auto" value set to the height property of the row containing the `TextBox`

Comment: StackPanel (so without any rows) has the same issue

Comment: I copied it to another empty WPF project and i still see the behavior that I have described. .NET Framework 4.5.2 (if it does matter...)

Comment: That's actually a pretty good question. It seems like it takes the lines under consideration only when it rerenders on keystrokes

Comment: Is release build produces same result?

Comment: @Spawn Yes - same issue

Answer (score 1):

So after playing with it for a while I got it working by binding the text to a property in the ViewModel

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" 
             SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True" 
             TextWrapping="Wrap"
             AcceptsTab="True" 
             MinLines="5"
             MaxLines="5"
             Text="{Binding Text}">
    </TextBox>
</Grid>
```

and

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        Text = "My Text";
    }

    public string Text { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

This makes me think the issue has something to do with the order WPF renders the controls to the screen, but not sure what exactly. This doesn't answer your question of why this is happening, however since the common usage of textboxes in an MVVM WPF applications would be done by bindings and not hard coded text, this should suffice as a solution.

Comment: I agree. I know that in the end there would be a binding. However I encountered this problem when prototyping in Blend. I do not want to waste my time on making viewmodels and bindings if I do not know if the views are correct. Any other solution?

Comment: @Pellared It is a good question though. I'll keep looking into it.